# List<T> RemoveAll() isn't removing items

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have an object that looks like this:

```
{
  "Text" : "Another lovely alert",
  "Category" : 2,
  "UserAlerts" : [{ "UserId" : 2 }]
}
```

This is passed to web API and bound correctly to:

```
[Key, Column(Order = 0)]
public long UserId { get; set; }

[Key, Column(Order = 1)]
public Guid AlertId { get; set; }

public virtual User User { get; set; }

public virtual Alert Alert { get; set; }
```

I then run the following, expecting the UserAlert with an ID of two to be removed, but the object is unchanged.

```
alert.UserAlerts.ToList().RemoveAll(x => userIds.Contains(x.UserId));

alert.UserAlerts.ToList().RemoveAll(x => x.UserId == 2);
```

The second query is simpler but this doesn't do anything either. I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's because by using `ToList` you are creating new List object and then remove items form it, not from original IEnumerable.

Try using this:

```
alert.UserAlerts = alert.UserAlerts.Where(x => x.UserId != 2);
```

You can't run `RemoveAll` on `IEnumerable`, so I think using Linq here is a good idea. You will have collection of items which do not have `UserId=2`, which is equivalent to removing all items with `UserId=2`. You need to reverse your query from `RemoveAll` and it will work in any case.

Answer (score 4):

That should certainly remove the elements, but I don't see how you would even notice whether it had or not?

First you create the list with `ToList()` and then you call `RemoveAll()` to remove some elements from that list, but since you haven't stored that list anywhere, you're just going to get the number of items removed back.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `RemoveAll` on `alert.UserAlerts`, because `ToList` creates a new collection.
If you remove all items of that collection, it does not change `UserAlerts`.

```
alert.UserAlerts.RemoveAll(x => userIds.Contains(x.UserId));
```

**Update:**
If `UserAlerts` is not a `List`, use the `Where` extension method (as wudzik said in his answer):

```
alert.UserAlerts = alert.UserAlerts.Where(x => !userIds.Contains(x.UserId));
```

Comment: `alert.UserAlerts` can be IEnumerable or IQueryAble instead of being a List

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now.  I can't run RemoveAll on UserAlerts because it is an ICollection, how do I cast to the appropriate type?

Comment: @DavidB when you'll cast it, it'll become new object

Comment: @DavidB if it is not a List, you should use the `Where` extension method and assign the new value to `UserAlerts`

Comment: @DavidB and negate predicate in `Where`

Comment: Thats great, thanks everyone for the help. I also needed to use ToList() on the result, as UserAlerts is an Icollection not Ienumerable