# How to modify original collection using SelectMany

Tags: c#

SelectMany seems to create a copy of the collection. I am looking for a way to remove items from the flattened collection and have the changes persist.

Example:

```
var removed = FooItems
.SelectMany(x => x.Children)
.ToList()
.RemoveAll(y => y.ID == "1");
```

The above all return 1 for the removed item, but seems its removed from a copy of the collection and the original is not modified.

Any tips please advise.

Comment: Linq is not suited for mutating the original collection.  Instead you should loop over `FooItems` and remove from each `Children` collection, possibly using `RemoveAll` if `Children` is a `List<T>`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `Children` is a `List<T>` then you can just loop over `FooItems` and remove from each `Children` list.

```
foreach(var foo in FooItems)
    foo.Children.RemoveAll(y => y.ID == "1");
```

If `Children` is not a `List<T>` but a `IEnumerable` then you'd have to do something else like

```
foreach(var foo in FooItems)
    foo.Children = foo.Children.Where(y => y.ID != "1").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `.SelectMany()` with `.RemoveAll()` and expect it to modify your original object.

That's because `.SelectMany()` returns an `IEnumerable`.
However, `.RemoveAll()` is a `List` method.

So, to use `.RemoveAll()` with `.SelectMany()` you will have to use `.ToList()` **which creates a new List of objects of your instance**.

See: [List RemoveAll() isn't removing items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33211594/listt-removeall-isnt-removing-items/33211634#33211634)